# Solr Config Error

Tags: tomcat, solr, solr4, rackspace

I installed Solr on a rackspace server. Tomcat was setup fine (port `8080` loads the default page), and I followed these instructions to set up Solr. But I got the error below:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration.
Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.
If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:
<abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError> in null -------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/conf/', cwd=/usr/share/tomcat6
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:262)
```

What file(s) did I need to edit the path for solr config?  It's currently in `/var/lib/tomcat6/solr/conf`

Comment: Tell more details, which Solr version did you use? Why you don't try distribution with Jetty?

Comment: I am using Solr 1.4.1  I had the wrong path in my web.xml. I changed it, but now I'm getting an error

type Status report

message /solr

description The requested resource (/solr) is not available.